# Как задать порядок систем в grub?

Tags: linux, grub, dual-boot, boot

Есть 3 системы: Windows, Linux Mint и Debian.

Сейчас список загрузки выглядит примерно так:

```
Windows
Debian
Дополнительные параметры для Debian
Linux Mint
Дополнительные параметры для Linux Mint
memtest
memtest serial console
```

Как сделать, чтобы Linux Mint был вторым?

```
Windows
Linux Mint
Дополнительные параметры для Linux Mint
Debian
Дополнительные параметры для Debian
memtest
memtest serial console
```

И возможно ли вообще получить следующий порядок?

```
Windows
Linux Mint
Debian
Дополнительные параметры для Linux Mint
Дополнительные параметры для Debian
memtest
memtest serial console
```

---

Windows и Debian установлены на первый физический диск (MBR)
Linux Mint установлен на второй физический диск (GPT)
UEFI нет, загрузка с первого диска.

Grub енастраиваю из Mint'а.

---

Предложенное в комментариях переименование файлов не помогает:

```
qwertiy-Z68AP-D3 grub.d # ls -l .
итого 92
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9424 мая   13 21:33 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11692 мая   13 21:33 03_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1180 окт.  25  2014 06_mint_theme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11620 нояб.  8  2015 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10634 окт.   1  2012 10_lupin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6058 мая   13 17:51 15_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10412 мая   13 21:33 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1992 марта 12  2014 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1416 мая   13 21:33 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 мая   13 21:33 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 мая   13 21:33 41_custom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   483 мая   13 21:33 README
qwertiy-Z68AP-D3 grub.d # update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
  No volume groups found
Найден Windows 7 (loader) на /dev/sda1
Найден Debian GNU/Linux (6.0.10) на /dev/sda5
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
завершено
qwertiy-Z68AP-D3 grub.d #
```

---

В `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` обнаружил, что Debian находится внутри

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/03_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/03_os-prober ###
```

Получается, он находит Windows и Debian вместе и манипуляции с порядком файлов ни к чему не приведут?

Comment: Можно посмотреть выхлоп ls -l /etc/grub.d/ ?

Comment: @donRumata, я сейчас в Windows'е. Список файлов того каталога: `00_header
05_debian_theme
06_mint_theme
10_linux
10_lupin
20_linux_xen
20_memtest86+
30_os-prober
30_uefi-firmware
40_custom
41_custom
README` Чтобы получить виндоуз первым, менял номера 30, 06 и 05 в разных вариантах, но поменять местами дебиан и минт не вышло. Приведённый порядок - оригинальный. Специально вернул его после экспериментов.

Comment: Т.е. mv 05_debian_theme 15_debian_theme && update-grub не помогает?

Comment: @donRumata, 15 не пробовал. Пробовал 07 - не помогало.

Comment: @donRumata, проверил не помогает. Вопрос дополнен.

Comment: @donRumata, вопрос ещё раз дополнен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно поменять местами секции `menuentry` в `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` так, как нужно. этот файл читается (и интерпретируется) загрузчиком при каждом запуске непосредственно, т.е. изменения файла как бы «подхватываются на лету».

[синтаксис секции](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Menu_002dspecific-commands):

```
menuentry "заголовок" [опции] { команды }
```

секции `menuentry` могут быть вложены в секции `submenu` (под-меню). итоговый файл может выглядеть, например, так:

```
submenu "заголовок" [опции] {
  menuentry "заголовок" [опции] { команды }
  menuentry "заголовок" [опции] { команды }
}
menuentry "заголовок" [опции] { команды }
```

---

недостаток: выполнение скрипта `/usr/sbin/update-grub` вернёт порядок записей «на круги своя». а вызывается этот скрипт, как минимум, при обновлении пакетов с программами `linux` и `grub`.

---

**дополнение**

ещё пишут, что можно воспользоваться пакетом [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer), среди возможностей которого:

- move, remove or rename menuentries (they stey updatable by update-grub)

недостаток: судя по сведениям из packages.ubuntu.com, пакет этот не включен ни в один из поддерживаемых репозиториев.

---

**дополнение 2**

чтобы файл `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` не перезаписывался при обновлении пакетов с программой *linux*, можно в скрипте `/usr/sbin/update-grub` заменить это имя файла на какое-нибудь другое (например, `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new`), и обновлять файл вручную. пример замены:

```
$ cat /usr/sbin/update-grub
#!/bin/sh
set -e
exec grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new "$@"
```

недостатки:

- придётся вручную поддерживать актуальность файла `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (основываясь на изменениях в `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new`).
- при обновлении пакета *grub2-common* (или иного, содержащего упомянутый скрипт `/usr/sbin/update-grub`), придётся вновь исправлять и `/usr/sbin/update-grub`, и `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: Вот еще [описан способ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus) в самом конце, использования своего файла `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` с `update-grub`

Comment: @zRrr, можно сделать и проще. см. **дополнение 2** к ответу.

Comment: apt/dpkg при обновлении пакета с `/usr/sbin/update-grub' положит новый файл рядом, с другим именем, или затрет изменения? Хотя мне кажется, что оба варианта плохо дружат с обновлениями.

Comment: @zRrr, перезапишет. вообще странный какой-то скрипт. по-правильному он должен бы читать имя конфигурационного файла из `/etc/default/grub`, и, лишь если оно там не задано, использовать умолчальное значение.

Comment: Установил rub-customizer - получилось поставить в нужном порядке. Спасибо.